# How to add folder in a rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

How can i add a directory in a htaccess rewrite rule ?

I like to rewrite from url: http://myurl.com/folder/content/a-file
to url: http://myurl.com/onemoredir/folder/content/a-file.foo

Thanks.

**EDIT:** And i like to do it only for the things in /content/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/folder/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteRule ^(content/.*)$ onemorefolder/$1 [L,NC]
```